# Position DIV relative to another DIV?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to position a DIV relative to another DIV? I imagine this can be done by first placing it inside of the reference DIV, and then using `position: relative`. However, I can't figure out how to do this without affecting the contents of the reference DIV. How can I do this properly?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/CDmGQ

Comment: what are you effecting of the grey div with the red div in that example?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean in 'without affecting the contents of the reference DIV'? Can you provide an image of the requested result?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First set `position` of the parent DIV to `relative` (specifying the offset, i.e. `left`, `top` etc. is not necessary) and then apply `position: absolute` to the child DIV with the offset you want.
It's simple and should do the trick well.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It works only if I add padding or margin, thus positions the second div below the first one.

Answer (score 17):

You need to set `postion:relative` of outer DIV and position:absolute of inner div.
Try this. Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CDmGQ/4/)

```css
#one
{
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin: 62px 258px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;   
}

#two
{
    background-color: #F00;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    top:10px;
}​
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `position: absolute` while inside the other div.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CDmGQ/1/)

Comment: `position: absolute` alone won't work; the specified offset will refer to the document body and not the parent div (at least in the demo you provided). See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `position:relative;` inside #one div and `position:absolute` inside #two div.
[you can see it](http://jsfiddle.net/wUrdM/)